# Magento 2 toggle shipping address form in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, shipping-address

I'm trying to implement a changes in checkout where by default, the shipping address fieldset is not visible for guest customer and when there's a certain button that toggle it to visible when it's click.

I've been playing around shipping.js but it seems it's not working. Any idea on how to implement this?